# ¿Cómo mostrar el formulario en el template?

Tags: html, django, django-forms, djangorestframework, django-urls

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from . import views
from blog.views import *
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls), # Esto no lo borres porque sino no vas a poder acceder al /admin
        url(r'^$', post_list, name='post_list'), # Si va al raiz www.tusitio.com que lo atienda el index
        url(r'^formulario/$', formulario, name='formulario'), # Si ingresa en www.tusitio.com/contactos entonces sera atendido por la vista de contactos
        url(r'^tabla/$', tabla, name='tabla'), # Si ingresa en www.tusitio.com/contactos entonces sera atendido por la vista de contactos
        url(r'^gracias/' , 'blog.views.gracias' , name='gracias')
]
```

formulario.html

```
{% load staticfiles %}
     <html>
            <head>
                <title>Sergito</title>
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
                <link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster&subset=latin,latin-ext' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/blog.css' %}">
            </head>
            <body>
                <div class="page-header" align="center">
                    <h1>Esto es una prueba</h1>
                    <a href="post_list">Inicio</a>
                    <a href="formulario">Formulario</a>
                    <a href="tabla">Tabla</a>
                </div>

        <div class="content" align="center">
                <form action="/blog/templates/blog/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
                    {{ form.as_table }}
                    <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
                </form>
       </div>


            </body>
        </html>
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.template import loader, Context
from django.core import serializers
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from .forms import formulario

def formulario(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = formulario(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/blog/templates/blog/gracias/')
    else:
        form = formulario()
        return render(request,'formulario.html',{
        'form': form,
        })
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms

class formulario(forms.Form):
    nombre = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    mensaje = forms.CharField()
    mail = forms.EmailField()
```

Comment: Hola, ¿cuál es el problema?

Answer (score 0):

Hay diferentes formas

```
{{form}} # con esta primera muestras todo el formulario

# También puedes mostrarlo campo a campo
{{form.nombre}}
{{form.mensaje}}
{{formación.mail}}

 # o también con un bucle 
 {% for field in form %} 
      {{field}}
 {% endfor %}
```

Los dos últimos te permiten personalizar la distribución así como el diseño, así que te recomendaría que uses uno de esos

Answer (score 0):

Pues la verdad que yo no veo un problema de renderización de formularios, lo que sí veo es que en el parámetro `action` estás haciendo el `post` a otro lado:

```
<form action="/blog/templates/blog/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_table }}
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
</form>
```

Cuando, según tus URLs debería ser a:

```
<form action="/formulario/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_table }}
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
</form>
```

O, usando la URL por su nombre:

```
<form action="{% url 'formulario' %}" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_table }}
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
</form>
```

Pareciera que le estás pasando la ruta de los templates en vez de las rutas de tus URLs. Por ejemplo:

```
return HttpResponseRedirect('/blog/templates/blog/gracias/')
```

Debería ser:

```
return HttpResponseRedirect('/gracias/')
```

O, en su defecto (usando [`reverse`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse) y el `name` que le has dado a la URL):

```
return reverse('gracias')
```